# Any recomended tool to keep track of the Rest API errors and exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have build an API for my rails app, can someone suggest a good monitoring tool to keep track of the exception that the API throws

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is subjective and it's likely to be closed. You may want to have a look at the [list of most common services](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/exception_notification) and find the one that most fits your needs.